# Javascript - loop through datepickers and set date

Tags: javascript

I don't know Javascript at all.  I have a form where there can be any number of datepicker textboxes.  When the user selects a date in the first datepicker textbox, then I want all the remaining datepicker textboxes to have that same date.

Does this require a function?

Edit:  I tried to create a function, but I don't know javascript at all!

```
    function UpdateValuationDates(event) {
        $valuationDatePicker = $(event.target);

        var valuationDate = $valuationDatePicker.datepicker("getDate");


        if (valuationDate != null) {
            //loop through all items


            document.getElementById("dateValuationDate").Text
                    $valuationDatePicker.datepicker("setDate", valuationDate);
            $valuationDatePicker.trigger('change');
        }
    }
```

So I think this can be ignored.  I have also read that there is a datepicker on selected event:

```
$(".date").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText) {
    display("Selected date: " + dateText + "; input's current value: " + this.value);
  }
});
```

So I guess I need to edit this code to populate the rest of the textboxes, but how to find out at runtime how many there are?

The HMTL has a repeater with the datepicker repeated x number of times:

```
 <abc:DatePicker runat="server" ID="dateValuationDate"
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: thanks - I have added more detail and I am trying some different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of html's `input type=date` and some basic classes' knowledge, you can do that.. Considering you have following Date pickers:

```
<input type="date" class="dateTime">
<input type="date" class="dateTime">
<input type="date" class="dateTime">
```

Now you simply need to listen to a change in any one of there values:

```
$(".dateTime").on("change", function(){
```

and when the change occurs, get the changed value and set all other date pickers to that new value:

```
$(".dateTime").val($(this).val());
```

So it'll be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dateTime").on("change", function(){
        $(".dateTime").val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/qmggchqe/)**

*EDIT:* Considering you're new to JavaScript, here's how i'm getting the reference to all those elements, through `.className`, as they all have same class name so for each event (change, update value) they all will be referenced.

Comment: does it matter that the datepickers are somehow repeated (i.e. there is only one datepicker in the html):  <abc:DatePicker runat="server" ID="dateValuationDate"

Comment: there are no class names in the HTML for the datepicker

Comment: would this work:   $("#dateValuationDate").on("change", function () {
                $("#dateValuationDate").val($(this).val());
            });

Comment: ok I am now using this, but nothing happens when I select a date in any of the datepickers, where does this code need to go:                           $(".textbox-datepicker").on("change", function () {
                $(".dateTime").val($(this).val());
            });

Comment: it works!  but there are other ".textbox-datepicker" on the page (expiry date, start date) - and it changes all those too!  Anyway to just change those, maybe using the id:   ID="dateValuationDate"

Comment: Change the classname of all those timepickers which you dont want to change.. Because .textbox-datepicker will change all fhe datepickers with that classname

Comment: Any way to elaborate - is this done in the CSS file? How do I tell the code to make these specific datepicker to have a different class?

Comment: You write it yourself in html.. See in the input tag class=